# push data from an array to a json format

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this js code that extract data from a json format and draw a d3js multiseries graph:
http://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/YaHjN/1/
But my input data will be in an array like this:

```
rows = array(
array(20111001,634,627,722),
array(20111002,580,599,677),
array(20111003,53.3,59.1,69.4),
array(20111004,55.7,58.8,68.0),
array(20111005,64.2,58.7,72.4),
array(20111006,58.8,57.0,77.0),
array(20111007,57.9,56.7,82.3),
array(20111008,61.8,56.8,78.9),
array(20111009,69.3,56.7,68.8),
 )
```

so I pushed the input data in my code to a json form like this

```
var data = [];
for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++) {
           data.push({x: rows[i][0], y: rows[i][1], z: rows[i][2],r: rows[i][3]});
          }

   // Coerce the strings to numbers.
   data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.x = +d.x;
   d.y = +d.y;
   d.z = +d.z;
   d.r = +d.r;
  });
```

but this is not working despite that the same trick worked before in an another example.

Comment: arrays are part of JSON too

Comment: yes I know but my input data is like defined above I want to use it at it is in my code(in the link)

Comment: It looks as though you are converting the first row into a number where it looks like a date.  You can use the parseDate variable you have previously made just make sure that you are parsing it a string, so the first line would become d.x = parseDate(d.x); and all the data in the first row would have to be in inverted comma's ("20111001").